# How AWS Load balancer affects response time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, response, load-balancing, ping

i am implementing some api for Real Time Bidding,
it requiers me to implement an http server.
but to keep it running i have to respond within `100ms`,
it also can get up to `50,000` requests per second so i have to
put a load balancer with many instances.
so, because response time is very valuable to me,

how the load balancer affect this?

Comment: AWS may not be the best choice in this situation. AWS is a multi-tenant virtualized environment. Which means resources being shared between multiple users. You will not have full control of latency.

Comment: im not going to use the micro instance so its not really shared... its virtualized but i get the full cpu and ram that i ordered

Comment: Unless you use dedicated instances, everything is shared. Noisy neighbors can reduce your expected CPU performance.

Comment: Micro Instances: "They are well suited for lower throughput applications and web sites that require additional compute cycles periodically". They are NOT recommended for production.

Comment: and you are writing this because...?

Answer (score -1):

SSL termination can chew up resources (CPU power). You can put this either on the Load Balancer or on the Web Servers but either way you need to consider if you really need SSL and what level of encryption you will use.

Keep in mind if you're going to get a spike in traffic you should pre-warm the load balancers.

Other then that the load balancer shouldn't really be the root use of latency, it's likely to be your Web Servers becoming saturated so make sure you setup auto-scaling with the right metrics for your app/traffic.

There are plenty of other things you can do to overload the work your web servers need to do (caching, APC for PHP, moving static files off to CDN, caching DB calls or using non-Relational DBs, using Nginx instead of Apache)

Edit: AWS ELB is built to scale automatically. I wasn't able to find figures on what the latency is and how this affects your response time. If you were interested you could test hitting the server directly vs hitting the LB but I suspect the results will be negligible. Hit your LB (or servers) with enough traffic and you'll see response times go way up.

Comment: i know about all the work, i have mongo db with redis caching, i just dont know about the time spent on the load balancer

Comment: do a test with your particular setup. Try with the LB and compare to without.